# How to install Android sdk on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, android

I want to start learning android programming to start my [first app](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) but as I see on [their site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) the system requirements:

> Operating Systems
>   Windows XP (32-bit), Vista (32- or 64-bit), or Windows 7 (32- or 64-bit)
>   Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later (x86 only)
>
> Linux (tested on Ubuntu Linux, Lucid Lynx)
>
> GNU C Library (glibc) 2.7 or later is required.

As you see there is nothing about windows 8, I searched for the problem and found few sites that offer a version compatible with windows 8 but I'm afraid they might contain viruses.

How can I install android sdk on windows 8?

Comment: If it supports being installed on Windows 7 then it supports Windows 8.  **Just follow the normal installation instructions.**

Comment: @Ramhound I've seen many programs that work on windows 7 and not on windows 8 I was just verifying if I can install android sdk without any problems.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason a program that worked on Windows 7 would not work on Windows 8.  I suggest in the future simply trying to install the application.  If its not supported it won't be installed or will crash when ran.

Comment: @Ramhound I faced this problem with [autocad](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?siteID=123112&id=19048377&linkID=12305695), and I wasted much of my time trying to uninstall and re install it to make it work.

Comment: My advice is still sound.  You don't lose any ( significant) amount time by installing and trying to run the program.

Comment: @Ramhound I do have slow internet connection so basically my time loss would be on downloading, and it would be much worse if downloading was useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default SDK from google works on windows 8. I use it. You need to have JAVA [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) installed before proceeding with SDK installation.

However if you are starting new using their [ADT](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) (Android Developer Tools) is suggested. And with ADT you already have the SDK.

Comment: thanks, I only wanted to verify that I can install it without any problems, I'll try to install the ADT.